# How to debug an UWP app in Release mode + ".Net Native tool chain"

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, native, release

I have developed an **UWP app** that works globally fine, but I encounter some problems with the **Store** app, or with the **Release** build, whereas all works fine in **Debug** build...

The app seems very basic: ts allows users to create and sync forms through webservices. At the launch of the app, a test is done to see if a user is already logged in: if it's not the case, the app navigates to the "**Login**" page, otherwise it navigates to the "**Home**" page, which contains the forms list. Then the user can edit each form through a "**Details**" page.

**"Debug" mode:**

When I build the app in "Debug" mode, I don't encounter any exception that isn't catched and **all works fine**.

**The Store app:**

The last version of the Store app has been successfully generated and validated without any problem. But one of my last changes raises a **crash of the app**, when the user coming back from the "**Details**" page to the "**Home**" page.

I suspect especially this change to raise the error: I've added some code on the "**Details**" view to clean the resources through "**OnNavigatedFrom**()":

```
protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    ViewModel = this.DataContext as DetailsViewModel;
    if (!ViewModel.ToChildNavigate)
    {
        // Dispose resources
        this.Resources.Clear();
        this.Loaded -= DetailsPage_Loaded;
        ViewModel = null;
    }
    base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);            
}
```

To fix this, I would like to build the app in "Release" mode with ".Net Native tool chain".

**"Release" mode:**

In "**Release**" mode, I have checked well the options "**Compile with .NET Native tool chain**" and "**Optimize code**".
[image]

The application launches correctly and navigates fine the "**Login**" page. But after the user's connection, the app tries to navigate to the "**Home**" page: I get **2 exceptions**, and I can't do anything else...

The first exception occurs one time, and I can "continue":
[image]

The second exceptions occurs each time even if I try to continue:
[image]

I've tried to add some **MessageDialog** to see where the error occurs, but the message is not displayed in the consctructors: so I can't identify the origin of the problem...

**"Debug" mode with "Native tool chain"**

Finally, I've tried to build the app in "Debug" mode again, but with the options "**Compile with .NET Native tool chain**" and "**Optimize code**".

But like this, it works fine, and I can't reproduce the error encountered in "Release" mode...

I don't have another ideas, and I can't anwser to these questions:

- why are there differences between the Store version and the Release mode?
- how could I done to use the app in Release mode? is it possible to "debug" it?
- I have to launch the app in Release mode to fixe the encountered bug of the Store version...

Regards,

Answer (score 3):

**Release** configurations by default **optimize the code** which loses some artifacts used for debugging. As a result, trying to debug a **Release** configuration can result in some issues.

> It is important to note that the Release configuration is by default fully optimized code (e.g. [code inlining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_expansion) will be applied in many places). These optimizations will have a significant impact on the debugging experience including **unpredictable stepping and breakpoint behavior** (due to code inlining) and the inability to inspect most variables due to memory optimizations.

So to debug a UWP app in "Release" mode, we can create a custom configuration and enable the .NET Native toolchain for that configuration. Make sure to not optimize code.

For more details please see [Debugging .NET Native Windows Universal Apps](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/07/29/debugging-net-native-windows-universal-apps/).

Comment: Thanks @Jay Zut: this didn't work for me. I have add a new configuration like in your link: `Release` with  `Compile with .NET Native toolchain` checked and  `Optimize code` unchecked. But the breakpoints are always unavalaible: "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this documen". You can see my other tests [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42256423/visual-studio-2015-i-cant-debug-and-use-breakpoints-in-release-mode)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem a while ago. After a long time of try and error i was able to debug in release mode with .net native tool chain with remote debugging on another pc (in my case it was a surface).

I used Visual Studio 2017 and on the remote machine the remote debugger tools for 2017.

Hope this helps.

Greetings.