# UWP app only works when visual studio 2017 is installed

Tags: uwp

I am making a desktop app, but it does not work on other windows 10 machines unless visual studio 2017 is also installed. I currently install the app manually. Later on it should be done through windows store.

Without visual studio, the app just shows it's window for half a second and quits. Any idea why?

The app has a few  xaml tags and also uses Media Foundation for video processing.

Comment: Did you try to debug your app in release mode? Debug and release mode has same difference in how code and exceptions are managed. I learned this the hard way....(here you can find some other info on this matter: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42208803/how-to-debug-an-uwp-app-in-release-mode-net-native-tool-chain)

Comment: Try to handle `UnhandledException` event in `App.cs` file and write exception into a file and read it via file explorer after next crush

Comment: The same happens to me when I delete the `bin` folder in the app's project. Have you tried creating a package using `Project > Store > Create app Packages` and then installing it using the PowerShell script which it generates? Will it run afterwards?